# python requests library pass comma separated ids as argument

Tags: python, python-requests

I am querying an API with the python requests library

this is using an internal API

I have this that works

```
ids=[24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760, 166787, 166788, 28666, 29792]
for i in ids:
    args={'segmentID': i}
    resp=requests.get('http://internal/api/segments?',params=args)
```

but I want to just pass through the entire list of ids which is allowed

http://internal/api/segments?segmentID=24381%2C+31883%2C++21145%2C+21143%2C+23010%2C+23016%2C+28066%2C+28163%2C+28673%2C+68665%2C+50750%2C+35268%2C+34943%2C+76377%2C+29760%2C+166787%2C+166788%2C+28666%2C+29792

this correctly works but I constructed this manually, how do i pass the ids through in python

this does not work

```
ids=[24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760, 166787, 166788, 28666, 29792]
args={'segmentID': ids}
resp=requests.get('http://internal/api/segments?',params=args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
ids=[24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760, 166787, 166788, 28666, 29792]

args={'segmentID': ",".join(str(i) for i in ids)}
resp=requests.get('http://internal/api/segments?',params=args)
```

**Note:** `%2C` means `,`

Answer (score 0):

That's because when making the request in the for loop it all goes as an int, not as a list.

```
args={'segmentID': 24381}
```

But when passing it as a list it results into something like

```
args={'segmentID': [24381, 31883]}
```

I think that this might work

```
ids=24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760, 166787, 166788, 28666, 29792
args={'segmentID': ids}
resp=requests.get('http://internal/api/segments?',params=args)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure `ids=24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760, 166787, 166788, 28666, 29792` ids will default to a tuple